# Will plastic sheeting against a wooden retaining wall preserve the wood?

Tags: landscaping

I'm looking for the way to make the pressure treated wood in my project last the longest possible. I want to put a piece of plastic (black) sheeting to protect the 2x12s being used for a new retainer wall. It will then be backfilled with dirt against the plastic, holding the plastic in place. Will this make the 2x12s last longer, or will it increase the rot time of the PT wood?

Comment: Keep in mind that PT timber is generally very moist from the store. If you seal it up right away in your construction, you'll be trapping all that moisture in. Granted, it's PT, but the extra moisture will still eventually be a problem and could easily hasten the demise of the wood rather than delay it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with dimple board instead of the plastic.  The dimpleboard will allow water to drain to the bottom of the retaining wall.

If you just go with plastic, assuming the retaining wall has air on one side, I'd expect it to last longer than without plastic.  I assume the soil being retained is wet more often than dry.

Comment: Yea, you really need to consider what will happen to all the water trapped behind the plastic.  There can be a lot of water.

Comment: To that point, I once built a free-standing planter box that way and lined the insides with sheet plastic. After about 3 weeks the weight of the water trapped in the soil cause everything to collapse...

Comment: We used MiraDRAIN for our PT wood retaining walls.  So far so good.

Answer (score 0):

Water does not cause the wood to rot (actually soaking is one way to preserve the greenwood), the frequent drying-wetting cycle does. If the water table is high, the pressure can build up behind the wall and causes problems. Do not place the plastic sheet behind the wall but use a drainable fabric instead, if you want to extend the service life of the wall.

Answer (score 0):

I'd worry about that plastic actually trapping water against your wood.

Generally, you want to ensure proper drainage. Surround your PT wood with the right aggregate and then surround that aggregate with a water permeable fabric. The fabric will allow water to drain but now allow dirt to clog up your aggregate.

TOH has a few videos on doing this. Here is one:
https://youtu.be/qaMPqKp6yvk

Answer (score -1):

I certainly hope so; I have done it with several retaining walls. Most are landscape cedar but one is treated lumber. Mine all have one side open to air. After 25 years some walls have badly deteriorated (50 inch nominal rainfall), but I have no comparison without plastic sheet.